# Dummy variable is not creating right in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am trying to create a dummy variable from a factor variable which looks about like this:

```
[1]    cva accident w rt hemiparesis          aphasial        dm type ii        htn    
6589 Levels:    cva accident w rt hemiparesis          aphasial        dm type ii        htn     ...
```

This is the code I have used to create the dummy variable:

```
random_merge_patients$'MedCond_HTN' <- ifelse(random_merge_patients$'MedCond' %in% "htn",1,0)
```

I receive no error messages but when I try to view `random_merge_patients$'MedCond_HTN'` I see that the values are all 0s even if there should be some 1s .

Any ideas what could be wrong with my code?

Comment: `random_merge_patients$MedCond_HTN<-ifelse(random_merge_patients$MedCond== "htn",1,0)`

Comment: I have tried == 'htn' but that did not make a difference. It seems that 'htn' is not being recognized in the factor MedCond

Comment: is it possible that there is some leading / trailing whitespace?

Comment: not sure about the white space. I have tried to use grepl function which runs and does what i expected:  grepl("*htn", random_merge_patients$'MedCond') == "htn"   (returns TRUEs and FALSEs)    But than the complete function: random_merge_patients$'MedCond_HTN'<-ifelse(grepl("*htn", random_merge_patients$'MedCond') == "htn",1,0) still not picks up "htn" in a factor

Comment: It may help to reduce this to a smaller problem with [reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). If you can provide some sample data, it would help.

Comment: i figured out. I saved logical grepl() in a new variable, and than put this variable into ifelse(htn==T,1,0)   that helped with creation of dummy variables.